# iphone app avaiblity

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

We have just had our iPhone Application approved. Review App Store is set to USA.

When we uploaded the app we first made the availability date the 14th of Jan. Seeing is is now live, we have changed the availability date to the 12th.

The app still isn't able to be viewed or downloaded though.

How long does it take for the availability date to update?

Thanks!

James

Comment: When you asked Apple, what did they say?

Comment: 14th this Month. No thanks please!

Comment: It went live within 2 hours of posting this message. Thanks for your help. 

You can view and download the app here: http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/beanhunter/id349940968?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

The updates to itunes go out several times a day.  A friend of mine at Apple calls it the 'train.'  It can take anywhere from a few minutes if you are right on time, up to 8 hours if you just missed the last train.

In my experience, I've never seen one of my apps take more than 4 hours.

BTW, Congratulations on the launch!

Comment: Thanks for this! Let's hope we got on the right (latest) train.